Self-adjoint unbounded linear operator
Consider the linear operator $A= - \phi_{xx} + \phi_{xxxx}$. The domain of $A$ is given by
\begin{align}
D(A)&=\{ \phi \in H^{4}(0,L): \phi(0)=\phi(L)=\phi_{x}(0)=\phi_{x}(L)=0 \} \\&= H^4(0,L) \cap H^2_0(0,L) \subset L^{2}(0,L).
\end{align}
I already proved that the operator is injective, but I don't know how to proceed for surjectivity. On the other hand I already proved that the operator is symmetric (which indicates that $D(A) \subset D(A^*))$ and I was trying to prove that $\operatorname{Range}(A \pm iId) = L^2(0,L)$ to conclude therefore that $A$ is self-adjoint.
Any insights or guidance on whether the surjectivity of $A$ and self-adjointness would be greatly appreciated.

Lax-Milgram, simple as that. By the boundary condition you imposed for
$H^4(0,L) \cap H^2_0(0,L)$, in a bigger space as follows
$$
V:= \{\phi\in H^1 \cap H^2:\; \phi(0)=\phi(L)=\phi_{x}(0)=\phi_{x}(L)=0 \}
$$
you have the condition for Lax-Milgram (by a Poincare-type inequality): there exists an $\alpha>0$
$$
B(\phi,\phi) = \|\phi_x\|^2_{L^2} +  \|\phi_{xx}\|^2_{L^2} \geq \alpha \left( \|\phi\|^2_{L^2} + \|\phi_x\|^2_{L^2} +  \|\phi_{xx}\|^2_{L^2}\right) =: \alpha\|\phi\|_{H^2}^2.
$$
Therefore, there exists a unique solution in $\phi\in V$ given any $f\in L^2$ for the following equation
$$
\int_{0}^L \phi_x \psi_x + \int_{0}^L \phi_{xx}\psi_{xx} = \int_0^L f\psi, \quad \text{ for any  }\psi \in V.
$$
Now by elliptic regularity, the weak solution is the strong solution as well (or a simple argument using int by parts then fundamental theorem of calculus of variation), i.e., $\phi$ satisfying the equation above is in $H^4$ as well. By the arbitrary of $f$, there goes the subjectivity.

Note that above is a PDE-flavored argument, you can also use a spectral theory-flavored solution to argue the operator $A$ is bounded below in that space, i.e., you wanna find the smallest eigenvalue (which is $>0$), and you are done.

The self-adjointness is pretty straightforward to verify by int by parts using the boundary condition you have, i.e., just show $A = A^*$, $(A\phi,\psi) = (\phi, A\psi)$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the inner product you define in $H$.

This operator admits an explicit inverse. It’s an integral operator
$$ Tf(x)=\int_{[0,L]} K(x,y) f(y)\, dy, $$
where the kernel $K$ has the form $K(x,y)=a^+e^x+b^+e^{-x}+c^+x+d^+$ for $x>y$, and $K(x,y)=a^-e^x+b^-e^{-x}+c^-x+d^-$ for $x<y$, for suitable parameters $a^\pm,b^\pm,c^\pm,d^\pm$ which depend on $y$. To find the constants explicitly, you impose that for fixed $y$, the function $x\mapsto K(x,y)$ is continuous up to second derivative, satisfies the boundary conditions, and that the third derivative has a jump of (positive) size $1$. Essentially, you want to impose that
$$ -\partial_x^2 K(\cdot,y)+\partial_x^4 K(x
\cdot,y)=\delta_{y} $$
distributionally for every $y\in[0,L]$, where $\delta_{y}$ is the Dirac delta centered at the point $y$. These should be $8$ conditions to find $8$ coefficients.
Once you find the coefficients, you should be able to prove by hand that $T$ is well-defined and maps $L^2$ to the domain of $A$. This should give the surjectivity. A similar strategy should work for the surjectivity of $A\pm i$.
